# Node:internal/fs/utils:348 throw err; [ENOTDIR] / error when starting a barebone bot for the first time

Tags: discord, discord.js

I will try to explain my problem the best way possible. I've just recently got back to Discord.js and Discord bot development. And oh boy, did they change the way it use to work.

Anywho, I've followed the [guide](https://discordjs.guide) from discord.js themselves, and yet I still face an issue.

Here is my hierarchy for the project :

```
csupload/
├── node_modules/
├── src/
├    ├── commands/
├    ├     ├── ping.js
├    ├     ├── server.js
├    ├     └── user.js
├    ├── deploy-commands.js
├    └── index.js
├── .eslintrc.json
├── config.json
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

I hope it is clear. The main concern I have is that I believe the problem is coming from my index.js file. Because when I run the deploy-commands.js script DiscordJS provides, I have no issues or errors.

The command being (while in the correct directory `cd src`) : `node deploy-commands.js`

It returns the correct stuff :

```
PS C:\dev\csupload\src> node deploy-commands.js
Started refreshing 3 application (/) commands.
Successfully reloaded 3 application (/) commands.
```

Those 3 commands being : [ping.js] [server.js] [user.js]

Here's my code of the script (that discord.js provides) :

```
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./../config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');

const commands = [];
// Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

// Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

// Construct and prepare an instance of the REST module
const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

// and deploy your commands!
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

        // The put method is used to fully refresh all commands in the guild with the current set
        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
    } catch (error) {
        // And of course, make sure you catch and log any errors!
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Now when I run the command (still in the src/ directory) : `node index.js`

Here's what I get :

```
PS C:\dev\csupload\src> node index.js
node:internal/fs/utils:348
    throw err;

Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir 'C:\dev\csupload\src\commands\ping.js'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1451:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\csupload\src\index.js:14:26)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  errno: -4052,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOTDIR',
  path: 'C:\\dev\\csupload\\src\\commands\\ping.js'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Here's the code in the index.js (also coming from discord.js) :

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./../config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

client.once(Events.ClientReady, () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
            await interaction.followUp({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        } else {
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

I hope my question is understandable, and if any of you has an idea, please let me know. My initial thought is that it's coming from an error in the file/folder paths, but I don't know where.

I just followed discordjs guide, and yet I got an error while trying to startup the bot for the first time.

Forgot to mention that when following the guide, the first bot test (without the slash commands) works perfectly.

I expected the bot to work as expected by the guide.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the first snippet works and the second raises the error? In your `const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);` the `folder` references to directory entries of the `commands` folder, doesn't it? As per your given folder structure, this `commands` folder only contains files but no subdirectories. Yet you are trying to `fs.readdirSync(commandsPath)`, ie reading a *file*  as if it was a *directory* And that's the error you are getting ...

Comment: Ohhhh, I understand. So I gotta add sub directories, to make it work. something like : `commands/ and then, inside -> fun/ -> utility/` Etc ?

That's what I understood from your answer, but thanks it clears up a lot.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks for this answer @derpirscher now that I have added subfolders, it works like a charm. I had to update the code with latest one. I believe the one on the docs is not working perfectly, so I used [this one](https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/main/code-samples/creating-your-bot/command-deployment/deploy-commands.js). Hope this can also help someone else.

Comment: Or you ditch that `fs.readdirSync(commandsPath),` and do `require(commandsPath)` instead. Ie ditch one level of your nested code structure